# Dynamic Form Yii2 - Multiple Input Fields - How to send array from form to controller

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I'm new in Yii2 Framework and now I have this issue :

I have a buton that duplicates the row by this function :

```
$("#addRowCellphone").click(function () {
    $('#dataCellphone tr:last').after(
        '<tr>' +
            '<td>'+$('#cellphone_ddd').val()+'</td>' +
            '<td>'+$('#cellphone_numero').val()+'</td>' +
            '<td>'+$('#cellphone_tipo').val()+'</td>' +
            '<td>'+$('#cellphone_principal').val()+'</td>' +

            '<td></td>' +
        '</tr>');
});
```

My html:

```
<?php

Modal::begin([
'header' => '<h2>Dados do Telefone</h2>',
'id' => 'telefoneModal',
]);

 ?>

 <div class="row">
<div class="col-md-2">
    <?= $form->field($telefoneModel, 'cellphone_ddd[]')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <?= $form->field($telefoneModel, 'cellphone_numero[]')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
    <?= $form->field($telefoneModel, 'cellphone_principal[]')->dropDownList(['S' => 'SIM', 'N' => 'NÃO'])->label('Principal?') ?>
</div>
```

But in my controller it comes just the last row added, doesn't send an Array with all info that I want.

Is there an special do send this multiple data ?

Comment: cant get anything from your provided code none of the js related code elements are provided `#addRowCellphone` ,`dataCellphone` nothing and the modal provided has no relevance

Comment: index your variables ie `cellphone_numero[0][]` `cellphone_numero[1][]`

this means modifying your clone function too